# Android Quiz App,back and next buttons issue

Tags: java, android

I am developing a quiz application,and im facing with a issue with back and next button. Here is the situation:

1. I have 40 questions in total,and in the java class of quiz i initialize an integer rowID=1
2. W
   hen I'm at the first position the button is disabled, but when I press next still it stays disabled, the same thing for next button
3. I have a TextView which shows the number of current question, and if I'm at the question number 40 and I press next again, it goes 41. it shouldn't go

Here is my code:

```
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.CountDownTimer;
   import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.text.Html;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.RadioGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;
   import com.google.gson.Gson;
   import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
   import com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker;

   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   import retrofit2.Call;
   import retrofit2.Callback;

   import static autoshkolla.almotech.org.autoshkollastudenti.R.id.testi;

   public class Activity_Quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
       SaveData saveData;
       String ApiKey;
       Dialog dialog;
       Gson gson;
       Button next_question, previous_question;
       int quizID, questionID, trueanswer, useranswer;
       int rowID = 1;
       String question, filename, mime, image;
       SQLiteDatabase db;
       TextView viewquestion, question_number, user_email, user_id, quiz_number;
       QuizAdapter quizAdapter;
       private AllLectureAdapter adapter;
       DbProductModel dbProductModel;
       List < Quiz_Data > lecture;
       RadioGroup my_answer;

       NumberPicker numberPicker;
       Button start_timer, stop_timer;
       MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
       TextView koha;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity__quiz);
           Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'><b>QUIZ</b></font>"));
           saveData = new SaveData(getApplication());
           gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
           ApiKey = "bearer " + saveData.getAutoUserToken();

           if (!saveData.getQuizStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
               myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(2400000, 1000);
               myCountDownTimer.start();
               loading();
               generate_quiz(ApiKey);
               saveData.setQuizStatus("in_progress");

           }

           question_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionnumber);
           user_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
           user_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
           quiz_number = (TextView) findViewById(testi);
           user_email.setText("Email : " + saveData.getAutoUserEmail());
           user_id.setText("ID : " + saveData.getAutoUserId() + "");

           next_question = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbtn);
           previous_question = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevbtn);
           viewquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
           my_answer = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.useranswer);
           final QuizSendModel results = new QuizSendModel();

           koha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

           if (rowID > 1 && rowID < 40) {
               previous_question.setEnabled(true);
               next_question.setEnabled(true);
           } else if (rowID == 40) {
               next_question.setEnabled(false);
           } else if (rowID == 1) {
               previous_question.setEnabled(false);
           }


           FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.gotoquestion);
           fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity_Quiz.this);
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.questions);
                   dialog.setCancelable(true);
                   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                   Button shiko = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.shikopyetje);
                   numberPicker = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);

                   dialog.show();

                   /* Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                    window.setLayout(400, 600);*/

                   shiko.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {

                           question_number.setText(String.valueOf(numberPicker.getValue()) + "/40");
                           String[] proj = {
                               UsersProvider.QUESTION,
                               UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER
                           };
                           String[] args = {
                               String.valueOf(numberPicker.getValue())
                           };
                           Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, proj, UsersProvider.ID_ROW + " = ?", args, null);
                           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                               do {

                                   viewquestion.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.QUESTION)));
                                   String uswanswradio = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER));

                                   if (uswanswradio == null) {
                                       my_answer.clearCheck();
                                   } else if (uswanswradio.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                       my_answer.check(R.id.radioJO);
                                   } else if (uswanswradio.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                       my_answer.check(R.id.radioPO);
                                   }
                               } while (c.moveToNext());
                           }
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });
               }
           });

           viewquestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                       do {
                           /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.NAME))+", "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.ADDRESS)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           System.out.println("emri : "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.NAME))+" address : "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.ADDRESS)));*/
                           results.setId_question(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.ID_QUESTION)));
                           results.setUser_answer(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER)));
                           System.out.println("pyetja : " + results.getId_question());
                           System.out.println("uans : " + results.getUser_answer());
                       } while (c.moveToNext());
                   }
               }
           });

           my_answer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

               public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                   int checkedId) {
                   if (checkedId == R.id.radioPO) {
                       useranswer = 1;
                   } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioJO) {
                       useranswer = 0;
                   }
                   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                   values.put(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER, useranswer);
                   String row = String.valueOf(rowID);
                   String[] whereArgs = {
                       row
                   };
                   getContentResolver().update(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, UsersProvider.ID_ROW + " =? ", whereArgs);
               }
           });

           previous_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   rowID = rowID - 1;

                   question_number.setText(rowID + "/40");
                   String[] proj = {
                       UsersProvider.QUESTION,
                       UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER
                   };
                   String[] args = {
                       String.valueOf(rowID)
                   };
                   Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, proj, UsersProvider.ID_ROW + " = ?", args, null);
                   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                       do {

                           viewquestion.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.QUESTION)));

                           String uswanswradio = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER));
                           System.out.println("pergjigjeeuserit : " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER)));
                           if (uswanswradio == null) {
                               my_answer.clearCheck();
                           } else if (uswanswradio.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                               my_answer.check(R.id.radioJO);
                           } else if (uswanswradio.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                               my_answer.check(R.id.radioPO);
                           }
                       } while (c.moveToNext());
                   }
               }
           });

           next_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   my_answer.clearCheck();
                   rowID = rowID + 1;

                   question_number.setText(rowID + "/40");
                   String[] proj = {
                       UsersProvider.QUESTION,
                       UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER
                   };
                   String[] args = {
                       String.valueOf(rowID)
                   };
                   Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, proj, UsersProvider.ID_ROW + " = ?", args, null);
                   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                       do {

                           viewquestion.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.QUESTION)));
                           String uswanswradio = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER));
                           if (uswanswradio == null) {
                               my_answer.clearCheck();
                           } else if (uswanswradio.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                               my_answer.check(R.id.radioJO);
                           } else if (uswanswradio.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                               my_answer.check(R.id.radioPO);
                           }
                       } while (c.moveToNext());
                   }

               }
           });

           String[] proj = {
               UsersProvider.QUESTION
           };
           String[] args = {
               String.valueOf(1)
           };
           Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, proj, UsersProvider.ID_ROW + " = ?", args, null);
           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   rowID = 1;

                   viewquestion.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UsersProvider.QUESTION)));
               } while (c.moveToNext());
           }
       }

       public void generate_quiz(String APIKEY) {
           API api = APIClient.getApi(APIKEY);
           Call < Quiz > totclient = api.quiz();
           totclient.enqueue(new Callback < Quiz > () {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call < Quiz > call, retrofit2.Response < Quiz > response) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
                   // Log.d(TAG, "Succes:" + response.body().isError());
                   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                   System.out.println("AllLectures:" + gson.toJson(response.body()));
                   System.out.println("quiz id:" + gson.toJson(response.body().getQuizNumber()));
                   quiz_number.setText("Testi : " + gson.toJson(response.body().getQuizNumber()));
                   if (!gson.toJson(response.body()).equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                       if (gson.toJson(response.body().getError()).equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                           getContentResolver().delete(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
                           lecture = response.body().getData();

                           final List < Quiz_Data > movies = response.body().getData();

                           for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
                               quizID = response.body().getQuizNumber();
                               questionID = response.body().getData().get(i).getId();
                               question = response.body().getData().get(i).getQuestion();
                               trueanswer = response.body().getData().get(i).getTrueAnswer();
                               filename = response.body().getData().get(i).getOriginalFilename();
                               mime = response.body().getData().get(i).getMime();
                               image = response.body().getData().get(i).getImage();

                               values.put(UsersProvider.QUESTION, question);
                               values.put(UsersProvider.ID_ROW, i + 1);
                               values.put(UsersProvider.ID_QUESTION, questionID);
                               values.put(UsersProvider.TRUE_ANSWER, trueanswer);
                               //  values.put(UsersProvider.USER_ANSWER,-1);
                               values.put(UsersProvider.ORIGINAL_FILENAME, filename);
                               values.put(UsersProvider.MIME, mime);
                               values.put(UsersProvider.IMAGE, image);
                               Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
                               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),uri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               System.out.println("URI :" + uri);

                           }


                       } else {

                       }
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sesioni juaj ka skaduar ju duhet te rilogoheni", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call < Quiz > call, Throwable t) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });
       }

       public void loading() {
           dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(Activity_Quiz.this)
               .title("Duke hyre ne sistem!")
               .content("Ju lutem prisni...")
               .progress(true, 0)
               .show();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           //handle the click on the back arrow click
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case android.R.id.home:
                   finish();
                   return true;
               default:
                   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
           }
       }


       public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

           public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
               super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
           }

           @Override
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

               int progress = (int)(millisUntilFinished / 10000);


               koha.setText("" + String.format("%d : %d",
                   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                   TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
           }

           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
               //finish();
               saveData.setQuizStatus("start");
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Koha mbaroi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons' states are only updated once since the logic is in onCreate.
Consider transferring that logic into a function and call it in the button's onClick handler after updating the rowID.

For example

```
private void updateButtonState() {
    if (rowID > 1 && rowID < 40) {
        previous_question.setEnabled(true);
        next_question.setEnabled(true);
    } else if (rowID == 40) {
        next_question.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (rowID == 1) {
        previous_question.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And in your onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    rowID = rowID - 1; // + 1 if next button
    updateButtonState();
    ...
}
```